# SQL WHERE clause that can exclude by integer but also include according to a date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

I want to be able to exclude 2 of the 5 possible integers in RowA, but include any rows before 1/1/2021 only. I've tried a HAVING clause with the date where I GROUP BY a created_date, but that returned an error. So this is my entire clause currently, I get a "this query returned 0 results" when I know there are results. I've tried the RowA NOT IN ('1', '2') by itself in the WHERE clause (WHERE RowA NOT IN ('1', '2')) and had results returned. Also tried just having the WHERE created_date <= 1/1/2021 and had results returned. Edited to include a picture showing sample data and desired results. Here's the formula as is, which returns 0 results:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE created_date <= 1/1/2021
  AND RowA NOT IN ('1', '2')
ORDER BY created_date
```

[image]

Comment: The query you posted won't even compile or run on any version of SQL.  Please include the exact code you currently have.

Comment: That is the exact code I had, aside from names of the table and fields. It worked for me and even returned results when I took out the AND clause. Kept it in here to depict all of the information I'd like to include/exclude.

Comment: Your Created_date datatype is date or varchar?

Comment: VarChar I believe

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select * from
(
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE created_date<'1/1/2021'
)A where RowA NOT IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried this one - the "A" after the closed parenthesis and before the "RowA" - what is that supposed to be?

Comment: @cpburke94, it's an alias of the subquery

Comment: Ah I see, I hadn't ever seen that before. Thank you for clarifying! I meant to write in my first comment above that that didn't work unfortunately and returned 0 results.

Comment: @cpburke94, then there are some other problems as result must come if your data is correct - you can check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eec18c28878496917985565e457a67f9

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL code shall work in BigQuery and give you the correct answer.
below I reproduced the expected result using your SQL code (with minor syntax revision)

```
WITH Table1 AS 
(
  SELECT t.*
  FROM UNNEST(
    ARRAY<STRUCT< created_date Date, RowA INT64 >>
    [("2021-1-7", 1),
     ("2020-12-29", 2),
     ("2020-11-30", 3),
     ("2020-3-5", 2),
     ("2021-2-2", 4),
     ("2020-9-7", 5),
     ("2021-1-30", 1)

    ]
  ) as t
)

SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE created_date <= "2021-1-1" 
AND RowA NOT IN (1, 2) ORDER BY created_date
```